# seeking advice to plot a nice 4 quadrant bubble plot on R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization, visualization

I am currently trying to plot a nice bubble plot on R. I have tried with ggplot and succeeded but the colors are too pale, and the size too small, and I am convinced it is possible to do a way better plot on R[image: Here is the plot I got using ggplot2] .
I thus tried using library(plotly), without success this time [image: Here is the plot I get using plotly]. I am not sure plotly is the best option too, as it gives interactive plots whereas ultimately I will want to export on PDF this plot (so I need the labels to appear on it without having to activate anything, as in an interactive plot). Does anyone have any ideas to plot this ?

Here is my code :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

 p <- ggplot(plot_3D, aes(x = actes_evolution_2020_2021, y = tx_0_nuit_2021)) + 
   geom_point(aes(color = regroupement, size = actes_2021), alpha = 0.5) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07",
                                "#FFB5C5", "#BF87B3", "#7F5AA2")) +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 12)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = ~ paste0(.x, '%'), limits = c(-100, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = ~ paste0(.x, '%'), limits = c(-100, 100)) +
  xlab("évolution du nombre d'actes entre 2020 et 2021") +
  ylab("taux de 0 nuits en 2021")
p

# And when trying with plotly

library(plotly)

colors <- c('#4AC6B7', '#1972A4', '#965F8A', '#FF7070', '#C61951')

fig <- plot_ly(plot_3D, x = ~actes_evolution_2020_2021, y = ~tx_0_nuit_2021,
               color = ~regroupement, size = ~actes_2021, colors = colors,
               type = "scatter", mode = "markers", sizes = c(min(plot_3D$actes_2021), 
max(plot_3D$actes_2021)),
               marker = list(symbol = "circle", sizemode = "diameter", 
                          line = list(width = 2, color = '#FFFFFF')),
           text = ~paste("Spécialité:", regroupement_elsan, "<br>nombre d'actes en 2021 
:", actes_2021,
                         "<br>taux de 0 nuit en 2021", tx_0_nuit_2021))

fig <- fig %>%
  layout(title = "Lien entre le nombre d'actes et le taux de séjours de moins de 24h",
     xaxis = list(title = "évolution du nombre d'actes entre 2021 et 2020",
                  gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                  range = c(2.003297660701705, 5.191505530708712),
                  type = 'log',
                  zerolinewidth = 1,
                  ticklen = 5,
                  gridwidth = 2),
      yaxis = list(title = "taux de 0 nuit en 2021",
                  gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                  range = c(36.12621671352166, 91.72921793264332),
                  zerolinewidth = 1,
                  ticklen = 5,
                  gridwith = 2),
      paper_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)',
      plot_bgcolor = 'rgb(243, 243, 243)')

fig
```

Here is the head of my dataset plot_3D, for reproducibility :

```
structure(list(code_1 = c("M01b", "C01", "C02", "C04", "M01", 
"Total"), regroupement = c("Endoscopies digestives", "Ortho (+ rhumato et 
rachis)", 
"Chirurgie digestive", "Uro-néphro", "Gastro", "autres"), actes_2019 = c(36079, 
29520, 14618, 6515, 9179, 33707), actes_2020 = c(30192, 25451, 
12845, 7376, 7933, 24154), actes_2021 = c(42333, 24055, 13735, 
8196, 6504, 26115), tx_0_nuit_2019 = c(96.0955377574371, 63.5718186783179, 
41.4435389988359, 36.2817362817363, 3.92397302268547, 783.752765264434
), tx_0_nuit_2020 = c(96.0936155567028, 67.3069146785281, 40.5855855855856, 
34.344262295082, 3.29588014981273, 895.206473285694), tx_0_nuit_2021 = 
c(96.7053774299419, 
73.2892690513219, 51.0503369005153, 41.9021364576154, 3.6068530207394, 
849.200890941822), actes_evolution_2019_2020 = c(-16.3169710912165, 
-13.7838753387534, -12.1288822000274, 13.2156561780507, -13.5744634491775, 
-28.3412940932151), actes_evolution_2020_2021 = c(40.2126391096979, 
-5.48504970335154, 6.92876605683145, 11.117136659436, -18.0133619059624, 
8.11873809720957)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change a bit your `layout` for both axis. You can use `ticksuffix` for the "%" and create a `range` from -100% to 100%. Also you can do the same for size as in ggplot like this:

```r
library(plotly)

colors <- c('#4AC6B7', '#1972A4', '#965F8A', '#FF7070', '#C61951')

fig <- plot_ly(plot_3D, x = ~actes_evolution_2020_2021, y = ~tx_0_nuit_2021, 
               text = ~paste("Spécialité:", regroupement, "<br>nombre d'actes en 2021:", actes_2021,
                              "<br>taux de 0 nuit en 2021", tx_0_nuit_2021), 
               type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', size = ~actes_2021, color = ~regroupement, colors = colors,
               marker = list(symbol = "circle", sizemode = "diameter", 
                             line = list(width = 2, color = '#FFFFFF')))

fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Lien entre le nombre d'actes et le taux de séjours de moins de 24h",
                      xaxis = list(title = "évolution du nombre d'actes entre 2021 et 2020",
                                   ticksuffix = "%",
                                   range = c(-100, 100)),
                      yaxis = list(title = "taux de 0 nuit en 2021",
                                   ticksuffix = "%",
                                   range = c(-100, 100)))

fig
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This is the hover of one bubble:

[image]

Comment: thanks ! do you know how I could make the hover appear permanently on the plot ?